# Another way to build database structure

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, architecture, storage

I have to optimize my little-big database, because it's too slow, maybe we'll find another solution together.

First of all let's talk about data that are stored in the database. There are two objects: `users` and let's say `messages`

*Users*

There is something like that:

```
 +----+---------+-------+-----+
 | id | user_id | login | etc |
 +----+---------+-------+-----+
 |  1 |  100001 |   A   | ....|
 |  2 |  100002 |   B   | ....|
 |  3 |  100003 |   C   | ....|
 |... |  ...... |  ...  | ....|
 +----+---------+-------+-----+
```

There is no problem inside this table. (Don't afraid of `id` and `user_id`. `user_id` is used by another application, so it has to be here.)

*Messages*

And the second table has some problem. Each user has for example messages like this:

```
 +----+---------+------+----+
 | id | user_id | from | to |
 +----+---------+------+----+
 |  1 |   1     | aab  | bbc|
 |  2 |   2     | vfd  | gfg|
 |  3 |   1     | aab  | bbc|
 |  4 |   1     | fge  | gfg|
 |  5 |   3     | aab  | gdf|
 |... |  ...... |  ... | ...|
 +----+---------+------+----+
```

There is no need to `edit` messages, but there should be an opportunity to updated the list of messages for the user. For example, an external service sends all user's messages to the db and the list has to be updated. 
And the most important thing is that there are about 30 Mio of users and average user has 500+ of messages. Another problem that I have to search through the field `from` and calculate number of matches. I designed a simple SQL query with join, but it takes too much time to get the data.

So...it's quite big amount of data. I decided not to use RDS (I used Postgresql) and decided to move to databases like `Clickhouse` and so on.

However I faced with a problem that for example `Clickhouse` doesn't support `UPDATE` statement.

To resolve this issues I decided to store messages as one row. So the table `Messages` should be like this:

```
                 Here I'd like to store messages in JSON format
                 {"from":"aaa", "to":bbe"}
                 {"from":"ret", "to":fdd"}
                 {"from":"gfd", "to":dgf"}
                    ||                        
                    \/
 +----+---------+----------+------+    And there I'd like to store the 
 | id | user_id | messages | hash | <= hash of the messages. 
 +----+---------+----------+------+
```

I think that full-text search inside the `messages` column will save some time resources and so on.

Do you have any ideas? :)

Comment: I must say that your question is very broad. First of all, which types are from and too columns? Second, how did you use indexes when you used PostgreSQL? Did you look into partitions?

Comment: `from` and `to` is varchar (255) and i didn't look into partitions... Could you provide some tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

In ClickHouse, the most optimal way is to store data in "big flat table".
So, you store every message in a separate row.
15 billion rows is Ok for ClickHouse, even on single node.

Also, it's reasonable to have each user attributes directly in messages table (pre-joined), so you don't need to do JOINs. It is suitable if user attributes are not updated.

These attributes will have repeated values for each users' message - it's Ok because ClickHouse compresses data well, especially repeated values.

If users' attributes are updated, consider to store users table in separate database and use 'External dictionaries' feature to join it.

If message is updated, just don't update it. Write another row with modified message to a table instead and leave old message as is.

Its important to have right primary key for your table. You should use table from MergeTree family, which constantly reorders data by primary key and so maintains efficiency of range queries. Primary key is not required to be unique, for example you could define primary key as just (from) if you would frequently write "from = ...", and if these queries must be processed in short time.

And you could use user_id as primary key: if queries by user id are frequent and must be processed as fast as possible, but then queries with predicate on 'from' will scan whole table (mind that ClickHouse do full scan efficiently).

If you need to fast lookup by many different attributes, you could just duplicate table with different primary keys. It's typically that table will be compressed well enough and you could afford to have data in few copies with different order for different range queries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when we have such a big dataset, `from` and `to` columns should be integers, if possible, as their comparison is faster.

Second, you should consider creating proper indexes. As each user has relatively few records (500 compared to 30M in total), it should give you a huge performance benefit.

If everything else fails, consider using partitions:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

In your case they would be dynamic, and hinder first time inserts immensely, so I would consider them only as last, if very efficient, resort.